# Has anyone tried IPVS as a load balancer for diameter protocol?

Tags: performance, tcp, load-balancing, diameter-protocol

I want to know if IPVS can be used as a load balancer for diameter protocol which has TCP base.

Answer (score 0):

From which I have experienced, IPVS can be used as a load balancer. I use it in a cluster-server configuration in which every server of the cluster executes application server, heartbeat and http services.

Answer (score 0):

I used LVS to balance diameter connections, it works fine
The possible issue is that it balances connections, not messages, so back end load will not be equal.